# get html content with paging stored in cookies

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have a page where i need to go to www.site.com/search/all and then i can use www.site.com/page/2 3 4 ...etc. If i go directly to www.site.com/page/2 i don't have anything because it's no stored in cookies by the first url (www.site.com/search/all).

I want to run all pages and get the content, but i only can get content from the first page, that's given to me by (www.site.com/search/all).

i've made a $context and used session_start() to check if it works, but no success.

Theres my code:

```
<?php

require 'simple_html_dom.php';


$opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
session_write_close(); // unlock the file

$f=10;

for($i=1;$i<=$f;$i++) {
if($i==1) {
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.site.com/search/all',false,$context);
session_start(); 
}
else {

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.site.com/page/$i',false,$context);
}

echo $i;

echo $html;

?>
```

The $html result it's always from the first page, it wont go to the next, i think because of the cookies.

Comment: Are you in control of thie site.com place? If not, you'll have to follow THEIR rules on how to make things work. Starting a session on your end has absolutely no effect on their end - THEY need to start a session there.

Comment: Then you'll have to simulate the proper surfing sequence on their site. Nothing you do with your php sessions will change how that site operates.